# Jquery Ajax List of DatabaseTable

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to display `employeeTbl` data via  jQuery Ajax call. Action method loads the data and showing the output from db data in an array. Kindly help me to get the proper View via jQuery Ajax Method.

Here is my controller code:

```
public JsonResult getData()
{
    List<employee> empList = new List<employee>();
    empList = db.employees.ToList();
    return Json(empList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

And this is the view I am rendering:

```
@model IEnumerable<jQueryPoject.Models.employee>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

     //   $(document).ready(function () {
       //     loadData();
        //});

        // Load Data Function
        function loadData() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/JsonView",
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    var html = '';
                    $.each("#tbody", result, function (key, item) {
                        html += '<tr>';
                        html += '<td>' + item.ID + '</td>';
                        html += '<td>' + item.Name + '</td>';
                        html += '<td>' + item.Age + '</td>';
                        html += '<td>' + item.Salary + '</td>';
                        html += '<td>' + item.Contact + '</td>';
                        html += '<td>' + item.Email + '</td>';
                        html += '</tr>';
                    });
                    $('.tbody').html(html);
                },
                error: function (errormessage) {
                    alert(errormessage.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>ASP.NET</h1>
        <p class="lead">ASP.NET is a free web framework for building great Web sites and Web applications using HTML, CSS and JavaScript.</p>
        <p><a href="http://asp.net" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />

    <div class="container">
        <table id="tbl" class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Salary</th>
                    <th>Contact</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is result I am getting:

```
    [{"ID":1,"Name":"Sami","Age":"25","Salary":"28000","Contact":"111","Email":"s.rehman@texitech.com"},
    {"ID":2,"Name":"Muhammad Sami ur Rehman","Age":"25","Salary":"38970","Contact":"111","Email":"s.rehman@texitech.com"},
    {"ID":3,"Name":"Bilawal Bhutto","Age":"28","Salary":"18000","Contact":"0213333333","Email":"b.bhutto@gmail.com"},
    {"ID":4,"Name":"Bilawal Bhutto","Age":"28","Salary":"18000","Contact":"0213333333","Email":"b.bhutto@gmail.com"},
    {"ID":5,"Name":"Bilawal Bhutto","Age":"22","Salary":"20000","Contact":"ghfhj","Email":"b.bhutto@gmail.com"},
    {"ID":6,"Name":"Bilawal Bhutto","Age":"22","Salary":"20000","Contact":"03128646765","Email":"b.bhutto@gmail.com"},
    {"ID":7,"Name":"Tehmina Jawed","Age":"22","Salary":"20000","Contact":"02134598989","Email":"tehmina.jawed@gmail.com"},
    {"ID":8,"Name":"Sameer BAloch","Age":"22","Salary":"200000","Contact":"111","Email":"samirehman621@gmail.com"},
    {"ID":9,"Name":"Ali Zaidi","Age":"22","Salary":"18000","Contact":"02134598989","Email":"ali.zaidi@yahoo.com"},
    {"ID":10,"Name":"Bilawal Bhutto","Age":"22","Salary":"20000","Contact":"0213333333","Email":"b.bhutto@gmail.com"},{"ID":11,"Name":"hmgm","Age":"22","Salary":"38970","Contact":"ghfhj","Email":"samirehman621@gmail.com"},
    {"ID":12,"Name":"Tehmina Jawed","Age":"22","Salary":"20000","Contact":"ghfhj","Email":"samirehman621@gmail.com"},
    {"ID":13,"Name":"Bilawal Bhutto","Age":"22","Salary":"20000","Contact":"ghfhj","Email":"b.bhutto@gmail.com"},{"ID":14,"Name":"hmgm","Age":"222","Salary":"20000","Contact":"111","Email":"samirehman621@gmail.com"},
    {"ID":15,"Name":"Bilawal Bhutto","Age":"222","Salary":"20000","Contact":"ghfhj","Email":"m.shariq@gmail.com"},
    {"ID":16,"Name":"Bilawal Bhutto","Age":"22","Salary":"20000","Contact":"0213333333","Email":"b.bhutto@gmail.com"},
    {"ID":17,"Name":"Bilawal Bhutto","Age":"26","Salary":"20000","Contact":"0213333333","Email":"b.bhutto@gmail.com"},
    {"ID":18,"Name":"Bilawal Bhutto","Age":"22","Salary":"18000","Contact":"ghfhj","Email":"asdas@f.com"},
    {"ID":19,"Name":"Muhammad Shariq","Age":"26","Salary":"38970","Contact":"0213333333","Email":"m.shariq@gmail.com"},
    {"ID":20,"Name":"Bilawal Bhutto","Age":"22","Salary":"20000","Contact":"0213333333","Email":"samirehman621@gmail.com"},
   {"ID":21,"Name":"Bilawal Bhutto","Age":"22","Salary":"20000","Contact":"0213333333","Email":"b.bhutto@gmail.com"},
   {"ID":22,"Name":"Bilawal Bhutto","Age":"22","Salary":"18000","Contact":"ghfhj","Email":"samirehman621@gmail.com"}, 

 {"ID":23,"Name":null,"Age":null,"Salary":null,"Contact":null,"Email":null}, 
 {"ID":24,"Name":"Tehmina Jawed","Age":"222","Salary":"20000","Contact":"111","Email":"m.shariq@gmail.com"},
 {"ID":25,"Name":null,"Age":null,"Salary":null,"Contact":null,"Email":null}]
```

Comment: `$.each(result, function (key, item) {` and `$('tbody').html(html);` (you do not have an element with `class="tbody"`)

Comment: Yes sir i have edited the code for checking purpose, it is "#tbl' class that i have assigned the id to the Table.

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have edited my post even now you can check my mistakes

Comment: You ignored both the errors in your code that I noted

Comment: @StephenMuecke sir can you plz help me to get my code fixed

Comment: Read my first comment! (copy and replace it exactly as I stated)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sir made the changes but nothing happend

Comment: What do you mean _nothing happened_? And where are you calling the `loadData()` function? And why are you using ajax anyway instead of passing a model to the view anyway

Comment: Sir load data function should be called at pageload, and i know how to do it with the data models but now im trying to learn doing this Ajax way

Comment: Well you have commented out your `$(document).ready(function () {` so how do you expect `loadData()` to be called (and using ajax for to get call the server again to get data which should have been sent in the first place is nonsense)

Comment: Sir Mistakenly it was commented out but in VS Code it is not

Comment: Debug your code!!! And remove all those duplicate scripts (you include 1 copy of `bootstrap.css` not 2 and 1 copy of `jquery`, not 4)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sir i have deleted the extra Scripts, and modified the code which you have defined above but im still having the same out that i have posted in my Question

Comment: If you have made all the changes I have noted previously, then it works fine (again - debug your script!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer of my question, found the solution on youtube.

JQuery Script of my View :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $.get("/Home/getData", {}, function (data) {
            var row;
            $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                row += "<tr><td>" + v.ID + "</td><td>" + v.Name + "</td><td>" + v.Age + "</td><td>" + v.Salary + "</td><td>" + v.Contact + "</td><td>" + v.Email + "</td></tr>";
            });
            $("#dataTable").append(row);
        })
    })
    </script>
```

And the Controller Code is Here:

```
 public JsonResult getData()
        {
            DataSet ds = db1.GetAllrecord();
            List<employee> empList = new List<employee>();
            foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                empList.Add(new employee
                {
                    ID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ID"]),
                    Name = dr["Name"].ToString(),
                    Age = dr["Age"].ToString(),
                    Salary = dr["Salary"].ToString(),
                    Contact = dr["Contact"].ToString(),
                    Email = dr["Email"].ToString()
                });
            }



            return Json(empList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);




        }
```

And Here is the Model Class Function :

```
 public DataSet GetAllrecord()

        {

            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("Select * from  employee", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            return ds;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

change class selector `.tbody` to `tbody` and it should work, where `tbody` is an element selector

```
$(result).each(function (key, item) {
    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td>' + item.ID + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + item.Name + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + item.Age + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + item.Salary + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + item.Contact + '</td>';
    html += '<td>' + item.Email + '</td>';
    html += '</tr>';
});

$('tbody').html(html);
```

Add `dataType`, the type which is expected back from Server

> `dataType: "json"` and `contentType: "application/json"`

Comment: Nothing happend still getting same result

Comment: Same result, nothing changed

Comment: Nothing happend sir

Comment: @MSamiUrRehman, Have you added both contentType and dataType? Can you post the updated code?

Comment: whether the returned`result`  is an object? console.log(result) if you're using chrome

Comment: Return result would be the list of employees from database

Answer (score 0):

Hey try the same as i did.

```
    // Load Data Function
    function loadData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Home/JsonView",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "json",
            success: function (result) {
                var html = '';
                var count = Object.keys(result).length;
                for(var i = 0; i< count; i++){
                    html += '<tr>';
                    html += '<td>' + result[i].ID + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + result[i].Name + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + result[i].Age + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + result[i].Salary + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + result[i].Contact + '</td>';
                    html += '<td>' + result[i].Email + '</td>';
                    html += '</tr>';
                }
                $('.tbody').html(html);
               // you could try append too
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                alert(errormessage.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

for looping a json data.

Comment: Nothing new sir, Same result

Comment: what do you have as a result ? it doesnt work ? or ?

Comment: are you sure that /Home/JsonView link is working properly ?

Comment: i have updated my code with correct function names but still having same result that i have mentioned in my Question.